# Select where join fails

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to Select all where a join fails:

something like:

```
    // Pseudo

    $unit = User::from( 'users' )
                        ->select( 'users.*' )
                        ->whereJoinFails( 'suppliers', 'users.id', '=', 'suppliers.user_id' );
```

I have tried:

```
    // Returns all users

    $unit = User::from( 'users' )
                        ->select( 'users.*' )
                        ->leftJoin( 'suppliers', 'users.id', '=', 'suppliers.user_id' );
```

and

```
    // Returns all users but the one that doesn't satisfy is duplicated

    $unit = User::from( 'users' )
                        ->select( 'users.*' )
                        ->join( 'suppliers', 'users.id', '!=', 'suppliers.user_id' );
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'join fails'?

Comment: Select all where the join just does not work. So... where there is no supplier relationship available

Comment: Do you mean where `foo != bar`?

Comment: We can LEFT JOIN with suppliers to get the left side data.

Comment: @prava But that would return ones that did satisfy the join... which it does.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - If I do != it returns back the whole list again.

Comment: So you are looking for users whose id is not in the suppliers table?

Comment: @andy yea that's right

Comment: ->leftJoin('suppliers', 'users.id', '=', 'suppliers.user_id')-> whereNull('suppliers.user_id')

Comment: Thanks man! Put as the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left Join will always display the data on the left side of the join even if it is null. This way you can see all the records that are missing in the suppliers table because it will show up as a null. This should work:

```
User::from( 'users' )
->select( 'users.*' )
->leftJoin('suppliers', 'users.id', '=', 'suppliers.user_id')
->whereNull('suppliers.user_id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution for this would be:

```
$cat = User::whereNotIn('id',
    DB::table('suppliers')->distinct()->lists('user_id')
)->get();
```

but in this case 2 queries to database would be executed, for example:

```
select distinct `user_id` from `suppliers`;
select * from `users` where `id` not in ('1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10');
```